# Render polygon in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d-rendering

How can I render n-sided polygon in **three.js**. It does not have geometry for that. I need it to be able to render both convex and concave polygons. So maybe there is a patch or workaround somewhere.
*Usage:*
The input will be **n** vertices which will make the n-sided polygon. However, all the vertices will be on the same plane and the output should be a rendered polygon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you can use the Shape Object for that?
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html

Comment: the link is not working, can you share new link which help me to draw n number of vertices polygon using buffer geometry or any other method. (THREE.Geometry is removed)